# How to parse date so timezone is not included?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, sharepoint-2010

Parsing info from a list into Javascript

Here is a line of data:

```
{"__metadata":{"uri":"BASE_URL/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/RFCExtract(1)","etag":"W/\"3\"","type":"Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.RFCExtractItem"},"Title":"Test New","Class":1,"Status":"Closed","Date":"/Date(1292112000000)/","RFCNumber":1}
```

NOte that the date field is like so : `"Date":"/Date(1292112000000)/`

The database list displays the date as `12/12/2010`

The technique below has the date set to one day earlier due to the timezone. How can I ignore this timezone adjustment, so the date replicates what ever the database displays?

```
var date=parseJsonDate(item.Date); 
console.log(date);  //Sat Dec 11 2010 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
dateField=date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getDate();
console.log(dateField); //2010-12-11
```

This should be a straightforward simple fix, I want this result to be the same value as reported by the database, JavaScript should not try to offer another view.

Update Just tried jQUery

```
var date=$.parseJSON(item.Date);
blows up due to unexpected token /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is assuming the date supplied is in UTC and doing the conversion. Try below.

```
var date=parseJsonDate(item.Date); 
console.log(date.toUTCString());  //Sun, 12 Dec 2010 00:00:00 GMT
dateField=date.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+(date.getUTCMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getUTCDate();
console.log(dateField); //2010-12-12
```

Comment: Thanks :) A little rusty right now, and I was searching for the answer.